# How to make that when you clicked <tr> marks checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys:) I have this code which when checkbox is clicked adds class "selected" to my < tr > in table. But how to make that it will work also when I click on my < tr > ?

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><img src="../gallery/thumbnails/1.png" alt=""></td>
    <td>tryb</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><img src="../gallery/thumbnails/2.png" alt=""></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
    }).change();
</script>
```

Comment: You want to use `closest("tr")` not `parents('tr')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add click event for `tr` also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
    }).change();

    $("tr").click(function(){
        if($(this).find(":checkbox").is(":checked"))
           $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked",false); 
        else
           $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked",true);

        $(":checkbox").change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works great but only, when I click on <tr>. When I click on checkbox nothing happens (except that now, when I click on <tr> It's also doesn't work)

Comment: you have to check for e.target. if e.target == checkbox then do not fire click event for tr.

Comment: @Axwell, that is because a click on the input is a click on the tr and call both function (which kinda cancel each other) you need to make a condition `if($(event.target).is(input)) return false;`

Comment: @Arjun use `prop`, not `attr`! And for optimisation : `[type="checkbox"]` instead of `':checkbox'` and finally `$(this).find("[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', function(){ return !this.checked; });;`

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon Could you post proper version ? I don't know js so it's hard for me.

Comment: @Axwell not gonna change directly his answer, but here's the code : http://jsfiddle.net/yR4Ld/1/

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon Now it works very well! Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

you can tigger checkbox click event, when `tr` clicks

```
$(':checkbox').change(function (event) {
    $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked).addClass("checkbox");
});

// when click on tr it trigger checkbox click event
$('tr').click(function(event) {
  if(!$(this).is('.checkbox')) {
   $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); 
  }
  $(this).removeClass('checkbox');
});
```

**UPDATE** use tricky way to prevent double effect in check box

Comment: Works in 50%. Clicking on the checkbox doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more event listener

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

And add `e.stopPropagation()` in your `checkbox` change handler -

```
$(':checkbox').change(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Should be `.prop('checked', function(){
    return !this.checked;
});` to make it toggle.